# I'm not understanding what's going on in this javascript object

Tags: javascript

I'm working on some of codeschool's javascript exercises and this part has me baffled.
In the function dontPanic, I'm not understanding what's going on at the end of this statement

```
location.weaponBulbs[location["ranger"+i].station-1][0].
```

Basically, the part where it says `station-1`. I'm not sure why it's subtracting 1 from the station object. I also don't understand the [0] after station-1. Which object or array is [0] referring to?

My guess was the [0] after station-1. is the assigned number for station but I really need some clarification. I don't want to continue on with this lesson without understanding this. I put a comment above the line I need help understanding.

```
var superBlinders = [ ["Firestorm", 4000], ["Solar Death Ray", 6000], ["Supernova",            12000] ];
var lighthouseRock = {
  gateClosed: true,
  weaponBulbs: superBlinders,
  capacity: 30,
  secretPassageTo: "Underwater Outpost",
  numRangers: 3,
  ranger1: {name: "Nick Walsh", skillz: "magnification burn", station: 2},
  ranger2: {name: "Drew Barontini", skillz: "uppercut launch", station: 3},
  ranger3: {name: "Christine Wong", skillz: "bomb defusing", station: 1}
};
function dontPanic (location){
  var list = "";
  for(var i = 1; i<=location.numRangers; i++){
//this is what I don't understand    
list = list + location["ranger" + i].name + ", man the " +
       location.weaponBulbs[location["ranger"+i].station-1][0] + 
       "!\n";
  }
  alert("Avast, me hearties!\n" + 
    "There be Pirates nearby! Stations!\n" + list);
}
dontPanic(lighthouseRock);
```

Comment: it's actually `location.weaponBulbs[( (location[ ("ranger"+i) ].station) - 1)][0]`

Comment: `station` is one-indexed, but arrays are zero-indexed. You have to subtract one when going from station numbers to elements of an array. As for the `[0]`, `weaponBulbs` is an array of arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because arrays a 0-indexed, and `location["ranger"+i].station` is likely 1-indexed. `location.weaponBulbs`  is an array, so `location.weaponBulbs[1]` actually represents the second element in the array, and similarly `location.weaponBulbs[10]` accesses the eleventh element.

By subtracting one from the integer `location['ranger'+i].station`, it will correctly access the relevant array value.

Answer (score 0):

`location.weaponBulbs` appears to be a two-dimensional array.

`location["ranger"+i].station-1` yields an integer, so the end result is

`location.weaponBulbs[n][0]`, where `n` is the value of `location["ranger"+i].station-1`

Answer (score 0):

It is selecting weapons from the `superBlinders` array.

Since the ranger numbers start from 1 up to 3, and the index of the array starts from 0 up to 2, you need to subtract 1 from the ranger numbers in order to directly map them to the weapons.

Answer (score 0):

1. `"ranger"+i` results in a string.
2. `location.weaponBulbs` is an array here - so possibly location looks like this...

   ```
   var location = {
   "weaponBulbs":superBlinders, /* this is an array again */
   ranger1: {name: "Nick Walsh", skillz: "magnification burn", station: 2},
   ranger2: {name: "Drew Barontini", skillz: "uppercut launch", station: 3},
   ranger3: {name: "Christine Wong", skillz: "bomb defusing", station: 1}
   ...
   }
   ```
3. `location["ranger"+i].station` would become an `int` in this
4. Finally for each `station`, it is lighting up a random `weaponBulb` intensity...

Whow I learned how to write a rock in javascript !!